# Error in EPA implementation causing an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, three.js, collision-detection

Im having a problem trying to follow this tutorial on the EPA algorithm: https://winter.dev/articles/epa-algorithm

Im using ThreeJS to implement it. Specifically i think the error is on this line:

`if ( normals[i].dot(support) > 0)`

I have also made sure that my GJK and Support functions are working correctly. Below is the full EPA implementation.

```
const epsilon = 0.001;

function EPA (polytope, colliderA, colliderB) {
    let faces = [
        0, 1, 2,
    0, 3, 1,
    0, 2, 3,
    1, 3, 2
    ];

    let [normals, minFace] = GetFaceNormals(polytope, faces);
    let minNormal = new THREE.Vector3();
    let minDistance = Number.MAX_VALUE;

    while (minDistance == Number.MAX_VALUE) {
        minNormal.copy(normals[minFace]);
        minDistance = normals[minFace].clone().w;
        console.log('minNormal:', minNormal);
        console.log('minDistance:', minDistance);

        let support = Support(colliderA, colliderB, minNormal);
        let sDistance = minNormal.dot(support);

        console.log('support:', support);
        console.log('sDistance:', sDistance);
        console.log('minDistance:', minDistance);
        console.log('normals: ', normals);

        if (Math.abs(sDistance - minDistance) > epsilon) {

            minDistance = Number.MAX_VALUE;
            let uniqueEdges = new Array();

            for (let i = 0; i < normals.length; i++) {
                console.log('SameDirection', SameDirection(normals[i], support));
                //if ( SameDirection(normals[i], support) ) {
                if ( normals[i].dot(support) > normals[i].dot(polytope[faces[i * 3]])) {
                    let f = i * 3;

                    AddIfUniqueEdge(uniqueEdges, faces, f, f + 1);
                    AddIfUniqueEdge(uniqueEdges, faces, f + 1, f + 2);
                    AddIfUniqueEdge(uniqueEdges, faces, f + 2, f);

                    faces[f + 2] = faces.pop();
                    faces[f + 1] = faces.pop();
                    faces[f] = faces.pop();

                    normals[i] = normals.pop();

                    i--;
                }
            }

            console.log('uniqueEdges:', uniqueEdges);

            let newFaces = new Array();

            for (let [edgeIndex1, edgeIndex2] of uniqueEdges) {
                newFaces.push(edgeIndex1);
                newFaces.push(edgeIndex2);
                newFaces.push(polytope.length);
            }

            console.log('newFaces:', newFaces);

            polytope.push(support);

            let [newNormals, newMinFace] = GetFaceNormals(polytope, newFaces);
            let oldMinDistance = Number.MAX_VALUE;

            for (let i = 0; i < normals.length; i++) {
                if (normals[i].w < oldMinDistance) {
                    oldMinDistance = normals[i].clone().w;
                    minFace = i;
                }
            }

            console.log('newNormals:', newNormals);
            console.log('newMinFace:', newMinFace);

            if (newNormals[newMinFace].w < oldMinDistance) {
                minFace = newMinFace + normals.length;
            }

            console.log('minFace:', minFace);

            faces = faces.concat(newFaces);
            normals = normals.concat(newNormals);
        }
    }

    console.log('normal: ' + minNormal);
    console.log('penetrationDepth: ' + minDistance);

    return {
        'normal': minNormal,
        'penetrationDepth': minDistance + epsilon
    };
}

function GetFaceNormals(polytope, faces) {
    let normals = new Array();
    let minTriangle = 0;
    let minDistance = Number.MAX_VALUE;

    for (let i = 0; i < faces.length; i += 3) {
        let a = polytope[faces[i]].clone();
        let b = polytope[faces[i + 1]].clone();
        let c = polytope[faces[i + 2]].clone();

        let normal = new THREE.Vector3().crossVectors(b.clone().sub(a), c.clone().sub(a)).normalize();
        let distance = normal.dot(a);

        if (distance < 0) {
            normal.negate();
            distance *= -1;
        }

        normals.push(new THREE.Vector4(normal.x, normal.y, normal.z, distance));

        if (distance < minDistance) {
            minTriangle = i / 3;
            minDistance = distance;
        }
    }

    return [ normals, minTriangle ];
}

function AddIfUniqueEdge(edges, faces, a, b) {
    let reverse = edges.findIndex(([edgeA, edgeB]) => edgeB == faces[a] && edgeA == faces[b]);

    if (reverse != -1) {
        edges.splice(reverse, 1);
    } else {
        edges.push([faces[a], faces[b]]);
    }
}
```

I have stepped through the code as it is running, and the condition never seems to be met when i am testing, causing the uniqueEdges array to never be filled, and eventually causing an infinite loop. I have also tried using `if ( normals[i].dot(support) > normals[i].dot(polytope[faces[i*3]]))` , which was suggested in the comments to avoid the formation of a concave polytope, causing longer or infinite iterations. This line is causing its own error, where when i reaches 4, and is multiplied by 3 to make 12, this index is out of the range of the faces array, which is only 12 long, causing an error as this index is undefined.